# How to get results from MySQL table that DO NOT match two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Have been trying to figure this one out all night and struggling. This question relates to a MySQL database.

I need to `SELECT` all of the records in one table that DO NOT appear in two other tables.

For example, take the following tables:

table1

```
| email     |  module | name    |
| a@ba.com  |  401    | Chris   |
| a@ba.com  |  402    | Chris   |
| a@ba.com  |  403    | Chris   |
| a@ba.com  |  404    | Chris   |
| a@ba.com  |  405    | Chris   |
| z@xy.com  |  401    | Anna    |
| z@xy.com  |  402    | Anna    |
| z@xy.com  |  403    | Anna    |
| z@xy.com  |  404    | Anna    |
| z@xy.com  |  405    | Anna    |
```

table2

```
| email     | module | requested |
| a@ba.com  | 402    | Yes       |
| a@ba.com  | 403    | No        |
| z@xy.com  | 403    | Yes       |
```

table3

```
| email     | module    | received |
| a@ba.com  | 405       | Yes      |
| z@xy.com  | 401       | No       |
| z@xy.com  | 404       | No       |
```

I need to be able to search through the three tables to find records where the email address matches. Then I would want to select all of the rows from `table1` where the module is unique to that table, i.e. it does not appear in either of the other two tables. For example, for the user named *Chris* I would expect the query to return the following results, as the two modules (*401* and *404*) do not appear in either of the other two tables:

```
| email     | module  | name   |
| a@ba.com  | 401     | Chris  |
| a@ba.com  | 404     | Chris  |
```

I've tried playing with different types of `JOIN` phrases and spent most of the evening trying to find an answer to this but to no avail. Can someone on here help?

Comment: Has any of the answers helped you? if so please accept the one that helped the most as the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`LEFT JOIN` should give you a good performance in MySQL :

```
SELECT t1.email
     , t1.module
     , t1.name
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.email = t2.email 
                                  AND t1.module = t2.module
               LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.email = t3.email
                                  AND t1.module = t3.module
WHERE t2.email IS NULL 
  AND t3.email IS NULL
```

Comment: t2 doesnt have a column ```name```, neither does t3. But other than that i think you are right

Comment: +1. This query (using anti-join pattern) will return all rows from `table1` where a "matching" row is not found in either `table2` or `table3`. (The OP specification isn't clear; the first part of the spec is, but the later description says "search through the three tables to find records where the email address matches". The query in this answer returns rows from table1 that don't match, independent of whether a matching email address exists in table2 and/or table3. (Perhaps this part of the specification is why OP was having difficulty?)

Comment: @spencer7593 : Well, maybe (I was sticking to the desired result), let's wait for the OP's clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS()
```

clause. This a variation of the [EXISTS()](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php) clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM table1 x
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT * FROM table2
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM table3
     ) y
    ON y.email = x.email 
   AND y.module = x.module
 WHERE y.module IS NULL;
```